# How can I see the POST requests's raw data as a serialised string in chrome?

Tags: http, network-programming, http-post

I am aware that under network -> header -> request-paylod I can get it but I want to get it as a raw concatenated single string, just like how it would be passed as data.

ie Like this:

```
'data': 'text=erfr&profile_ids[]=5d5cc01f6156a2038439ed34&shorten=True&top=True&now=False&media[progress]=100&media[thumbnail]=https%3A//media-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/5d5cbf9724a8cd2bad4dd493/5d6c803cf36f59534b69ede7/output/thumbnail_00001.png&media[uploading_type]=video&media[uploaded]=True&media[video[details[location]]]=https%3A//media-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/5d5cbf9724a8cd2bad4dd493/5d6c803cf36f59534b69ede7/0fd7bc9e4ff936e66c83443194d5354a.original.mp4&'
```

Not like this

```
   "args":{
      "text":"erfr",
      "profile_ids":[
         "5d5cc01f6156a2038439ed34"
      ],
      "shorten":true,
      "top":false,
      "now":false,
      "service_geolocation_id":"109524955741121",
      "service_geolocation_name":"India",
      "media":{
         "progress":100,
         "uploaded":true,
         "uploading_type":"video",
         "video":{
            "title":"03_47_UTC_teamfk",
            "id":"5d6ce3aba1e0ab1afe4f5b24",
            "details":{
               "location":"https://media-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/5d5cbf9724a8cd2bad4dd493/5d6ce3aba1e0ab1afe4f5b24/e7e9f1d06809c408f2fc83053fc6115b.original.mp4",
               "transcoded_location":"https://media-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/5d5cbf9724a8cd2bad4dd493/5d6ce3aba1e0ab1afe4f5b24/output/e7e9f1d06809c408f2fc83053fc6115b.original.mp4",
            },
            "thumbnails":[
               "https://media-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/5d5cbf9724a8cd2bad4dd493/5d6ce3aba1e0ab1afe4f5b24/output/thumbnail_00001.png"
            ]
         },
         "thumbnail":"https://media-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/5d5cbf9724a8cd2bad4dd493/5d6ce3aba1e0ab1afe4f5b24/output/thumbnail_00001.png"
      }
   }
```

I just found the appropiate term:

I need `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type equivalent request of a request with content type `application/json`

Comment: @bigdataolddriver read question properly

Comment: Well you can't, you'll see what is actually sent. If you want to convert one payload type to another, you'll have to find a plugin or (web) application that does this, or write one yourself. Also, how to convert nested objects and arrays depends on the web framework that receives the payload.